# what is the difference between one way function and hard core predicate?

Tags: one-way-function, hard-core-predicate

Does anyone know what the difference between a one way function is and a hard core predicate? Are they related to each other or different?

Comment: basic difference (not complete): Hard-code predicates always output a single bit, one way functions may output more.

Comment: Indeed, one-way functions _must_ output more for sufficiently long inputs. $\;$

Comment: See the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard-core_predicate wikipedia article.

Comment: Thank you for reply! So I'm not understanding this statement that you can easily compute given 'x' but hard to compute given f(x). I guess I'm not entirely understanding what exactly is a hard core predicate...